# Laptop (hp dv4 media edition) not starting windows

Tags: windows-7, boot

My windows was running smoothly during an update of anti virus. After the download it  required a restart and did that automatically. Once it restarted the computer, the machine got stuck at the windows startup screen. I tried a manual restart and was given the option "repair your computer" reason given was "you computer failed to start in last instance".

I tried the startup recovery tool and it completed its working but no changes. I am running the windows now in directory services restore mode with safe mode on.

My understandings are
A. either the windows theme is having some issue
B. some service is stopping the startup
C. a recent update caused this crash
D. some virus is stopping the loading process

I when tried to recover windows found that all my recovery points has been deleted.

Please suggest what to do?

Comment: First, please don't use... after every sentence, it makes reading hard. Did you take a back up of your files?

Comment: What antivirus are you using?

Comment: Also, which version of Windows?

Comment: When you say "I when tried to recover windows found that all my recovery points has been deleted", do you mean `System Restore`?

Comment: @Dave: Yes I have taken a back up of my files

Comment: @MalwareManiac: McAfee.

Comment: @Karan: windows 7 home edition

Comment: @CharlieRB: YES it is system restore points. I was using the utility startup recovery provided by windows.

Comment: In that case, reinstall! Or, get a new hard drive, install a new OS to that and use your current HD as a slave, copy all the data (just in case the back up didn't do everything) then reformat the 'old' hard drive. It's not (IMO) conclusive if this is just an OS issue or not a hard drive issue either - SpinRite will check your hard drive without booting into Windows.

Comment: @Anzar Im almost positive the problem is Mcafee corrupting. In the last few months Ive fixed multiple computers with similar issues and as soon as I uninstalled Mcafee it would work just fine. I dont know how you would go about uninstalling in this case though